# How to add variable into controller/header.php

Tags: php, opencart

I have this site and I want to put some  in header for SEO purposes. The H1 must contain manufacturer name (brand) and product code (model).

So the problem is that I'm not sure how to put this variables in controller's file so I could call them in template file next.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: What templating system are you using?

Comment: Opencart 1.5.1.3 (it's in tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it! Added this code to controller/common/header.php

```
if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = $this->request->get['product_id'];
    } else {
        $product_id = 0;
    }

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

    $this->data['product_info'] = $product_info;

    if ($product_info) {

        $this->data['manufacturer'] = $product_info['manufacturer'];
        $this->data['model'] = $product_info['model'];

    }
```

And this to theme/default/template/common/header.tpl

```
<?php echo $product_info['manufacturer']; ?> <?php echo $product_info['model']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way around this would be to edit the product controller

```
catalog/controller/product/product.php
```

and change the heading there. It's set with

```
$this->document->setTitle($product_info['name']);
```

so you just need to prepend/append the manufacturer name there, such as

```
$this->document->setTitle($product_info['name'] . ' ' . $product_info['manufacturer']);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond but that's not the point. Timer.bg - that's the site and I want some <h1> sentence above the logo. I need it to be visible for users.
I added this code in header.tmp <?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?> <?php echo $product['model']; ?> and I have to add some code to controller/common/header.php
The point is what this code should look like :)

Comment: That's going to be a lot more cumbersome. You will have to add a new method to the document class, assign the manufacturer from the product controller and then in the header, retrieve that and add it to the view